# вычисления в python prettytable

Tags: python, prettytable

Вот, имеем,

```
H=10
q=0.8
d=0.1 
P=d
r=P/q
over=q*r
S=0.9*r
Lbor=H+over
Lv=Lbor-S
Q=P*(Lbor-S)
a=Q/(q*r*H)
b=r
```

В первые 4 строки я могу вводить любые данные. И далее print все сама вызовет.

А нужно задать в 8-ю строку несколько Lbor подряд, cкажем Lbor = 15, Lbor = 12,Lbor = 18 и т.д. например до 10.

Т.е. чтобы print последовательно пробежал по всем заданным мною в произвольном порядке  Llbor =х.

И далее, чтобы print все оформила в виде таблицы до 10 строк.

Вот такой:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

table = PrettyTable()
```

Вот с такими 7-ю columns (названиями) и 10-ю row (результатами)??
И здесь опять проблема?? Чем заполнить [  ]

```
N=list(range(1,11))
Lbor=H+over [  ]
S=0.9*r  [  ]
Lv=Lbor-S  [  ]
Q=P*(Lbor-S)  [  ]
a=Q/(q*r*H)  [  ]
b=r  [  ]

columns = {
    'N':  ,
    'Lbor': ,
    'S': ,
    'Lv': ,
    'Q': ,
    'a':  ,
    'b':  ,

}    

for key, item in columns.items():
table.add_column(key, item)

print(table)
```

Comment: мало что понятно.  print ничего не считает. А ``[ ]`` (это называется список) заполняют теми данными, которые нужны. Обычно автору это известно лучше, чем посторонним людям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я ничего не знаю про `prettytable`, иду в гугл, по одной из первых ссылок нахожу [такой пример](https://zetcode.com/python/prettytable/):

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
    
x = PrettyTable()

x.field_names = ["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"]

x.add_row(["Adelaide", 1295, 1158259, 600.5])
x.add_row(["Brisbane", 5905, 1857594, 1146.4])
x.add_row(["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7])
x.add_row(["Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5])
x.add_row(["Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8])
x.add_row(["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9])
x.add_row(["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4])

print(x)
```

Тут идет построчное добавление данных (`add_row` - добавить строку) вместо добавления колонок, как вам показали в ответе на один из ваших вопросов. По-моему так удобнее работать. В цикле просто вычисляете, все что нужно вывести в строку, потом добавляете строку с этими данными в таблицу. Пример:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
    
table = PrettyTable()

table.field_names = ['N', 'Lbor', 'S', 'Lv', 'Q', 'a', 'b']

H=10
q=0.8
d=0.1

table.float_format = '.2'  # Ставим округление в таблице до 2 знаков после запятой

for N in range(1, 11):
    # Все вычисляем
    P=d
    r=P/q
    over=q*r
    Lbor=N+over
    S=0.9*r
    Lv=Lbor-S
    Q=P*(Lbor-S)
    a=Q/(q*r*H)
    b=r

    # Добавляем новой строкой в таблицу
    table.add_row([N, Lbor, S, Lv, Q, a, b])

print(table)
```

Вывод:

```
+----+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
| N  |  Lbor |  S   |  Lv  |  Q   |  a   |  b   |
+----+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1  |  1.10 | 0.11 | 0.99 | 0.10 | 0.10 | 0.12 |
| 2  |  2.10 | 0.11 | 1.99 | 0.20 | 0.20 | 0.12 |
| 3  |  3.10 | 0.11 | 2.99 | 0.30 | 0.30 | 0.12 |
| 4  |  4.10 | 0.11 | 3.99 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.12 |
| 5  |  5.10 | 0.11 | 4.99 | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.12 |
| 6  |  6.10 | 0.11 | 5.99 | 0.60 | 0.60 | 0.12 |
| 7  |  7.10 | 0.11 | 6.99 | 0.70 | 0.70 | 0.12 |
| 8  |  8.10 | 0.11 | 7.99 | 0.80 | 0.80 | 0.12 |
| 9  |  9.10 | 0.11 | 8.99 | 0.90 | 0.90 | 0.12 |
| 10 | 10.10 | 0.11 | 9.99 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 0.12 |
+----+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

В формулах поменял `Lbor=H+over` на `Lbor=N+over`, т.к. все строки были одинаковыми. За правильность исправления не отвечаю, это только для примера.

Comment: Супер! Однако менять  H на N не надо, т.к. на H завязаны другие расчеты, например a=Q/(q*r*H)

Comment: N  это номер по порядку!

Comment: @сергей замечательно. Я уже написал, что это только пример. Вы можете поправить формулу у себя, как вам нужно.

Comment: а как добавить N в таблицу слева, например от 1 до 50

Comment: @сергей поменять range(1, 11) на range(1, 51)