# обратные вычисления в python prettytable

Tags: python, prettytable

вот такой код

```
H = 10
print(H)
q = 0.8
print(q)
r = 21/q
print(r)
Ovr = q*r
print(Ovr)
L = H+Ovr
print(L)
Lv = L*.2
print(Lv)
Q = L/6
print(Q)
a = Q/(q*r*H)
print(a)
```

Все расчеты делаются последовательно и завязаны на первую позицию H = 10, которую можно изменять.
А как, допустим, все завязать на L и начать с нее.

Comment: можете привести в вопросе результат (таблицу), которую вы хотите получить? Также надо указать какие переменные являются независимыми или константами. Если `q` - независимая переменная, то `Ovr = q * r = q * 21 / q = 21`, т.е. после упрощения `Ovr = 21` (константа)

Comment: таблица будет потом, сначала надо разобраться со строками. А упрощение не годиться, может быть и другая формула Ovr. Надо все автоматизировать!

Comment: без примера результата, который вы хотите получить этот вопрос напоминает мне [задачу о семи красных линиях](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BctbPxfVQ8) :-D PS и, кстати, как вам уже говорили в других ваших вопросах, prettytable предназначен исключительно для того, чтобы красиво выводить на печать табличные данные - вычислять он ничего не умеет. Возможно вам стоит ознакомиться с [модулем Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html) - он умеет и то и другое.

Comment: вот мне уже отвечали, как бы все таки считает https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253925/вычисления-в-python-prettytable/1254779#1254779

Comment: в том ответе `prettytable` используется только для печати - все расчеты делаются в цикле)

Comment: ну дык мне цикл и нужен, только в данном примере, а потом применю  в табличном виде

Comment: Ну дык вы и покажите в вопросе пример того, что хотите получить ;)

Comment: изменять произвольно L допустим 10 раз, L=12, L=13, L=24 и т.д. затем запустить цикл 10 раз в в виде таблицы и получить r, ovr и др. 10 раз с различными данными?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто выразите все переменные используя переменные `q`, `r` и `L`:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

def calc(L, q, r):
    Ovr = q*r
    H = L - Ovr  # 21 - константа
    Lv = L*.2
    Q = L/6
    a = Q/(q*r*H)
    return [L, q, r, H, Lv, Q, a]

L = [12, 13, 24, 27, 31]
q = 0.8
r = 21/q

columns = ['L','q','r','H','Lv','Q','a']
tab = PrettyTable(field_names=columns, float_format=".2")
tab.add_rows([calc(l, q, r) for l in L])
print(tab)
```

результат:

```
+----+------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+
| L  |  q   |   r   |   H   |  Lv  |  Q   |   a   |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+
| 12 | 0.80 | 26.25 | -9.00 | 2.40 | 2.00 | -0.01 |
| 13 | 0.80 | 26.25 | -8.00 | 2.60 | 2.17 | -0.01 |
| 24 | 0.80 | 26.25 |  3.00 | 4.80 | 4.00 |  0.06 |
| 27 | 0.80 | 26.25 |  6.00 | 5.40 | 4.50 |  0.04 |
| 31 | 0.80 | 26.25 | 10.00 | 6.20 | 5.17 |  0.02 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+
```